# How to stub an API when testing with Selenium Server

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, stub, e2e-testing

I'm using Nightwatch.js to test a MERN stack application—it makes calls to the Twilio API when it receives a `POST` request at `/sms/outgoing/`.

I would rather not send SMS messages every time I run my e2e tests—instead I'd like to stub out the behaviour and, ideally, return the request data, so that I can check my app is submitting the correct info.

I have looked at libraries such as [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) and [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock), but neither of these will work with tests that rely on selenium.

Is there a library that can intercept requests made by Selenium Server and provide the stubbing behaviour I'm after?

Comment: What is a Selenium **Webserver**? I am only familar with [tag:selenium-webdriver] and [tag:selenium-server].

Comment: @SiKing sorry, I meant selenium server

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned `nock` and `fetch-mock`, I assume you're using a node server?

If that is the case, you could modify the server to detect an environment variable `process.env.MOCK_API` and return hard-coded responses to fetch request using [fetch-reply-with](https://github.com/john-doherty/fetch-reply-with)